# Multiplicación de dos listas

Tags: python, lista, funciones

Me gustaría poder multiplicar dos listas de diferente tamaño de tal forma que se multiplique cada elemento de la lista por todos los elementos de la otra como se muestra a continuación:

```py
lista1=[2,3,4]

lista2=[5,7,9,6,4]

#resultado esperado

a=[10,14,18,12,8]

b=[15,21,27,18,12]

c=[20,28,36,24,16]
```

Esto de debería hacer para un numero indefinido de datos, pueden ser listas de diferentes tamaños.

Comment: voto por convertir esto a wiki ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando un generador:

```
def mult_listas(lis1, lis2):
    for a in lis1:
        yield [x*a for x in lis2]
```

En cada llamada genera una sublista de valores múltiplicados.

#### Demo

```
lista1=[2,3,4]
lista2=[5,7,9,6,4]

def mult_listas(lis1, lis2):
    for a in lis1:
        yield [x*a for x in lis2]

for sublista in mult_listas(lista1, lista2):
    print(sublista)
```

produce:

```
[10, 14, 18, 12, 8]
[15, 21, 27, 18, 12]
[20, 28, 36, 24, 16]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar cada resultado en diccionario. Este lo puedes crear con ayuda de la función `zip()` y una pequeña comprensión de lista.

Primero vamos a definir los nombres de los resultados de las operaciones en una lista junto a un diccionario vacío.

```py
nombres = ["a","b","c"]
result = {}
```

Luego solo debemos escribir el ciclo `for` y la comprensión de lista (que es un ciclo `for` simplificado y compacto). Con el ciclo `for` iteraremos en el resultado de `zip()` que podemos descompones en 2 valores `name, val` donde `name` será el nombre asignado a la operación con el número y `val` será el número en si. Luego utilizamos la comprensión de lista para multiplicar el número por cada elemento de `lista2` y lo añadimos al diccionario.

```py
for name, val in zip(nombres, lista1):
    result[name] = [val* val2 for val2 in lista2]
print(result)
```

Esto da como resultado:

```
{'a': [10, 14, 18, 12, 8],
 'b': [15, 21, 27, 18, 12],
 'c': [20, 28, 36, 24, 16]}
```

Por si te lo preguntas, si puedes crear variables en base a esto y sin haber definido ninguna anteriormente, pero en mi opinión la primera forma es fácil, pero si te interesa tener los resultados en variables en si, puedes usar el diccionario global de variables (`globals()`) para crear nuevas variables.

```py
nombres = ["a","b","c"]
for name, val in zip(nombres, lista1):
    my_vars = globals()
    my_vars[name] = [val* val2 for val2 in lista2]

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Dando como resultado:

```
[10, 14, 18, 12, 8]
[15, 21, 27, 18, 12]
[20, 28, 36, 24, 16]
```

Con `globals()` puedes acceder a donde se guardan todas las variables globales y al ser un diccionario puedes crear una nueva variable de la forma en que crearía una nueva clave `dict[key] = value`.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta más breve se logra con `numpy` una vez caes en la cuenta que lo que estás preguntando es en realidad un producto matricial de una matriz columna por una matriz fila:

```
import numpy as np
lista1=[2,3,4]
lista2 = [5,7,9,6,4]

np.array([lista1]).T @ np.array([lista2])
```

La última línea hace el producto matricial (operador  `@`) entre una matriz columna que contiene los números de `lista1` (la `.T` hace la transpuesta, para que sea columna) y una matriz-fila que contiene los números de `lista2`.

El resultado de esa línea es el siguiente:

```
array([[10, 14, 18, 12,  8],
       [15, 21, 27, 18, 12],
       [20, 28, 36, 24, 16]])
```

De hecho, si quieres cada fila en una variable como planteas en la pregunta, puedes hacer:

```
a, b, c = np.array([lista1]).T @ np.array([lista2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Una variante podría ser generando una **lista** con **sublistas** de resultados.

```
lista1=[2,3,4]
lista2=[5,7,9,6,4]
```

#### Multiplicación de listas generando sublistas con resultados

Necesitamos multiplicar los elementos de la primer lista por todos los elementos de la segunda lista. Quiere decir que si nuestra primer lista tiene 3 elementos, generara 3 sublistas con los resultados de sus multiplicaciones.

Para realizarlo de esta manera necesitaremos primero crear una lista temporaria donde se estarán agregando los resultados de las multiplicación.

Tenemos **lista1** con 3 elementos:

```
lista1=[2,3,4]
lista2=[5,7,9,6,4]
```

La multiplicación será el **primer elemento** de lista1 por **todos los elementos** de la lista2:

Resultado:

```
# 2*5, 2*7, 2*9, 2*6, 2*4
[10, 14, 18, 12, 8] 


def multiplicarListas(lista1,lista2):
    listaContenedora=[]
    sublista=[]
    for i in range(len(lista1)) :
        for j in range(len(lista2)):
            sublista.append(lista1[i]*lista2[j])
        listaContenedora.append(sublista)
        sublista=[]
    return listaContenedora
```

**listaContenedora** : guarda todas las listas generadas

**sublista**: guarda los resultados de los elementos multiplicados para luego agregarla a la listaContenedora. Al finalizar el recorrido, **sublista=[]** es vaciada para poder adicionar los elementos de la próxima sublista.

Al finalizar todo el recorrido de la lista1 devuelve una **lista** con las sublistas de resultados.

Para ver los resultados hacemos un print():

```
listaFinal = multiplicarListas(lista1,lista2)
print(listaFinal)
```

Devolverá una lista con sublistas:

```
[[10, 14, 18, 12, 8], [15, 21, 27, 18, 12], [20, 28, 36, 24, 16]]
```

#### Acceder a las sublistas:

```
print("Sublista 1: ", listaFinal[0])
print("Sublista 2: ", listaFinal[1])
print("Sublista 3: ", listaFinal[2])

Sublista 1:  [10, 14, 18, 12, 8]
Sublista 2:  [15, 21, 27, 18, 12]
Sublista 3:  [20, 28, 36, 24, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta respuesta la quería hacer con el objetivo de pasar a comprensión de generador la [respuesta de Candid Moe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/503146/158880) y a comprensión de diccionario [la de Christian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/503118/158880). Además de profundizar un poco.

#### Sobre la respuesta de Candid Moe

El código ofrecido por Candid Moe puede convertirse a una comprensión de generadores. Es decir esto:

```
def mult_listas(lis1, lis2):
    for a in lis1:
        yield [x*a for x in lis2]
```

Se puede convertir en esto:

```
([x*a for x in lis2] for a in lis1)
```

Su demo quedaría así

```
for sublista in ([x*a for x in lis2] for a in lis1):
    print(sublista)
```

Si quieres guardar cada lista en una variable, puedes hacer:

```
a, b, c = ([x*a for x in lis2] for a in lis1)
```

Mi propuesta asume que siempre va a haber 3 listas. Si hay mas o menos de 3, esta idea va a fallar. Si la cantidad de items de lis1 NO es constante, podrías trabajar con una lista de listas.
Es decir, en lugar de usar una comprensión de generador (que devuelve un generador, no una lista) puedes usar la comprensión de listas y acceder a cada lista según su posición. Es tan simple como cambiar los parentesis por corchetes:

```
listas = [[x*a for x in lis2] for a in lis1]
# imprime la cuarta lista.
print(listas[3])
```

Si quieres acceder por "nombre" a la lista y no por posicion, mira la respuesta de Christian y mi propuesta aquí.

#### Sobre la respuesta de Christian

###### 1- La primera propuesta

La primera propuesta puede simplificarse a una comprensión de diccionarios:

```
result = {name:[val* val2 for val2 in lista2] for name, val in zip(nombres, lista1)}
```

###### 2- La segunda propuesta

Intenté pasar esta propuesta a una comprensión, pero vi que al hacerlo así era más lento. Lo único que tengo que decir de esto es que si quieres afectar las variables locales de una función no vas a poder incluso obteniendo el diccionario de las variables locales con la función locals (en el caso de globals, agregar una clave a dicho diccionario crea una variable global, cosa que no pasa con el diccionario devuelto por locals) (creeme, ya lo he intentado antes sin exito).

---

Puedes hayar más información sobre la magica comprensión aquí: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/