# ¿Cómo usar un bucle for para cambiar el nombre de diferentes variables de dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe que quiero filtrar y guardar esos elementos filtrados en diferentes variables, para eso quiero ponerle el nombre a las variables de una columna (*GPI*) del mismo dataframe. Para eso quiero utilizar un bucle for.

```py
print(data_3.shape)
GPI=data_3.GP.unique()
print(GPI)

for i in GPI:
    data_i=data_3[data_3.GP=='i']
    print (data_i)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que me faltará?

Comment: tal vez te sirva esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/503118/183782

Comment: Bienvenido Julio Ceballos a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por cambiar el nombre de una variable?

Comment: quiero cambiar la variable data_i y colocarle el nombre de la columna GPI y se haga de forma automatica, espero que me de a entender.

Comment: pues no, sigue sin entenderse... quieres que la propia variable cambie de nombre o que cambie su contenido? Y si es lo primero ¿qué puede significar que una variable cambie de nombre? ¿No sería entonces otra variable? Y por otro lado el hecho de que la hayas llamado `data_i` siendo `i` el índice del bucle me hace sospechar de que quizás pretendes que su nombre vaya variando como `data_uno` , `data_dos`, etc.. en cada iteración del bucle? No sería eso equivalente a tener un diccionario `data["uno"]`, `data["dos"]`, etc.?  Y qué significa la comparación `=='i'`? Es todo muy confuso

Comment: Para aclararlo puedes mostrar cómo es el dataframe con que trabajas (o un fragmento de él) y qué variables querrías que salieran como resultado, junto con sus valores.

Comment: Si es lo que te dice @abulafia, no existe lo de cambiar el nombre de una variable, una variable vive y muere con el mismo nombre, eventualmente podrías crear variables de forma dinámica con el nombre que quieras pero es una práctica poco recomendada y para nada habitual.

Comment: así es es lo que quiero hacer que `data_i` vaya cambiando de acuerdo a una columna que esta en el dataframe y `== 'i' ` es para filtrar el dataset. Que el nombre de la variable sea el de los elementos que hay en la columna de ese dataset, subiré una imagen del dataset.

Answer (score 0):

A la vista de tu ejemplo, deduzco que lo que pretendes hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Determinar los diferentes valores que aparecen en la columna "GP" de tu dataframe (eso ya lo has logrado correctamente usando `data_3.GP.unique()`)
2. Separar el dataframe en "sub-dataframes", según cada uno de esos posibles valores.
3. Asignar cada "sub-dataframe" a una variable separada, haciendo que el nombre de la variable dependa automáticamente del valor de GP que se esté procesando.

El punto 3 es el que tienes que re-pensar un poco. Aunque es posible crear variables cuyo nombre sea computado por el programa, en general casi nunca es buena idea hacer eso. Suele ser mucho más útil crear un diccionario, que actúa a muchos efectos como las variables que buscas, haciendo que las claves del diccionario sean los nombres y los valores del diccionario sean los sub-dataframes que buscabas.

El tener un diccionario en vez de un montón de variables separadas hace más fácil procesamientos posteriores mediante bucles que iteren por el diccionario. Así puedes por ejemplo obtener estadísticas de cada uno de los sub-dataframes, o guardar en disco cada uno de ellos, etc.

Así que una implementación bastante directa de lo que buscas, pero con diccionarios, sería algo así:

```py
nombres = df.GP.unique()
data = {}

for nombre in nombres:
  data[nombre] = data_3[data_3.GP==nombre]
```

Al finalizar este bucle tendrás en `resultado` un diccionario cuyas claves son los "nombres de variable" a que te referías en la pregunta. Puedes por ejemplo acceder a cada una de ellas así:

```py
print(data["AG1"])
```

pero como mencionaba antes, el hecho de tenerlas en un diccionario, te permite iterar por las claves y valores para otros tipos de procesamiento. Por ejemplo, contar cuántas entradas tiene cada sub-dataframe:

```py
for clave, valor in data:
  elementos = len(valor)
  print(f"data[{clave}] tiene {elementos} elementos")
```

Otro ejemplo, crear un archivo csv separado para guardar cada sub-dataframe:

```py
for clave, valor in data:
  nombre_fichero = f"data_{clave}.csv"
  valor.to_csv(nombre_fichero)
  print(f"Generado el fichero {nombre_fichero}")
```

Este tipo de bucles no podrías hacerlos si tuvieras las diferentes variables `data_*` por las que preguntabas en la pregunta. De todas formas, si insistes en crear variables separadas, déjame un comentario y te mostraría cómo podría hacerse manipulando el diccionario `globals()` (aunque no es práctica común y sería menos útil).